# Writing 3D array to text file and then reading text file into array

Tags: c++, arrays, io

After printing the deck to the screen, I want to save this 3D array into a text file. And ultimately be able to read this text file back into a deck of sorts. However, when I do all I get for a text file is "usdeck" represented in hex. I tried putting the below code but it doesnt work...help?

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("unshuffled deck.txt");
myfile << usdeck;
myfile.close;


// deck of cards
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const char usdeck[4][13][14] = 
{
{"heart two", "heart three", "heart four",
"heart five", "heart six", "heart seven",
"heart eight","heart nine", "heart ten",
"heart jack","heart queen", "heart king",
"heart ace"},
{"diamond two", "diamond three", "diamond four",
"diamond five", "diamond six", "diamond seven",
"diamond eight", "diamond nine", "diamond ten",
"diamond jack", "diamond queen", "diamond king",
"diamond ace"},
{"club two", "club three", "club four", "club five",
"club six", "club seven", "club eight", "club nine",
"club ten", "club jack", "club queen", "club king",
"club ace"},
{"spade two", "spade three", "spade four",
"spade five", "spade six", "spade seven",
"spade eight", "spade nine", "spade ten",
"spade jack", "spade queen", "spade king",
"spade ace"}
};

for(int row=0;row<4; row++)
{
for(int column=0;column<13;column++)
    {
    for(int element=0;element<14;element++)
        {
    cout << usdeck[row][column][element] << " ";
        }
    cout <<endl;
}
}


return 0;

}
```

Comment: You do some work to output the text to `cout` - why do you believe that this work will just magically do itself when outputting to a stream backed by file, rather than console? You need to run the same loops, only replace `cout` with `myfile`. Better still, write a function taking `ostream&` as a parameter and printing to that stream; then call it twice - once with `cout` and again with `myfile`.

Comment: i cant get the information to correctly write to a text file, it appears in chinese. i replaced cout with "myfile.txt" for example but when i open up the text file it is in chinese lettering?

Comment: I tried using ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("decktext.txt");
for(int row=0;row<4; row++)
{
 for(int column=0;column<13;column++)
  {
  for(int element=0;element<14;element++)
   {
  myfile << usdeck[row][column][element] << " ";
   }
  myfile <<endl;
 }
}
myfile.close();
cout<< decktext.rdbuf();

Comment: `cout<< decktext.rdbuf();` This shouldn't compile. There is no variable named `decktext` declared in your program.

Comment: then how do i read from the text file i make back into the terminal

Comment: Similarly to how you wrote to it - via an object of type `ifstream`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change your data structure.  You are beginning to see the difficulties as you progress.

To write data to a file and read it back, you will need to structure the data for ease of reading.  I recommend one entry per line.  This will allow the use of the `std::istream::getline` function to read it back.

Pardon my style, but I like to place spaces between operators for readability. :-)

**Output to file:**

```
for (unsigned int r = 0; r < 4; ++r)
{
  for (unsigned int c = 0; c < 13; ++c)
  {
    data_file << usdeck[r][c] << '\n';
  }
}
```

**Input from file:**

```
for (unsigned int r = 0; r < 4; ++r)
{
  unsigned int c = 0;
  for (c = 0; c < 13; ++c)
  {
    // Read in the data and test for success.
    if (!data_file.getline(&usdeck[r][c][0], '\n', 14))
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (c < 13)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

### A Better Data Structure

In my opinion, your data structure is difficult to use.  Most computers were not designed to efficiently process text strings; they were designed to handle numbers more efficiently.  So, let's use a data structure for numbers.

Since the quantities of cards in a suite is not negative and the number of suits in a deck is not negative, we'll use `unsigned` integers.  This will allow the compiler to check our code for errors better.

Let's look at a deck.  It is made up of 52 cards:  13 cards per suit and 4 suits.  We could represent a card as some object that has a value and a suit:

```
enum Suit_Type {Heart, Diamond, Spade, Club};
struct Card
{
  Suit_Type     suit;
  unsigned int  value;
};
```

With this representation, every `Card` has a suit and a value.

So, a `Deck` must be a container of cards:

```
const unsigned int CARDS_PER_DECK = 52;  // 13 cards per suit * 4 suits.
unsigned int Deck[CARDS_PER_DECK];  // A container of cards.
```

In most card games, card's don't stay in the deck, they move from deck to player.  The array can be case that cards come in, but we need something more flexible.  A data structure where we can remove cards from and the container will shrink to fit.  Let's try `std::vector`:

```
  std::vector<Card> deck1(CARDS_PER_DECK);
```

The `std::vector` can also be useful for each player:

```
  std::vector<Card> player1;
  std::vector<Card> player2;
```

Initialization of the deck is left as an exercise for the OP.

In most card games, cards travel from a central deck to a player:

```
  player1.push_back(deck1.back());
  deck.pop_back();
  player2.push_back(deck1.back());
  deck.pop_back();
```

Since this is C++, methods can be added to the `Card` structure for ordering, reading, and writing of  `Card` instances.

Free standing functions can be created for analyzing a player's hand (which is a vector of cards).

**Writing of a `Card`**
A simple method for writing a card to an output stream:

```
    struct Card
    {
      Suit_Type     suit;
      unsigned int  value;
      void write(std::ostream& out)
      {
        static const char value_name[] =
        {
          "zero", "Ace", "two", "three", "four",
          "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",
          "ten", "jack", "queen", "king"
        }
        switch(suit)
        {
           case Heart: out << "heart "; break;
           case Diamond: out << "diamond "; break;
           case Spade: out << "spade "; break;
           case Club: out << "club "; break;
        }
        out << value_name[value] << "\n"; // one card per line.
      }
    };
```

To output a card to the console:

```
Card c;
c.suite = Club;
c.value = 1;
c.write(cout);
```

To output a card to a file:

```
  ofstream card_file("cards.txt");
  c.write(card_file);
```

To output a player's hand:

```
  std::vector<Card>::const_iterator iter;
  for (iter =  player1.begin();
       iter != player1.end();
       ++iter)
  {
    iter->write(cout);
  }
```

These are just a few of the benefits of changing your data structure.